# twitter-video twitter-video-error not related to API documentation, how to fix it?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter, embed

Which is an example of an html request response to api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.{format} by Twitter API 1.1 that don't cause a **twitter-video-error** when the Widgets script `widgets.js`?

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Request the API with: 1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id=672098352037785600&maxwidth=500&hide_thread=true&omit_script=true&align=center&widget_type=video&hide_tweet=true
2. Bind in a single div, written BY HAND, the code inside the html property of the response. Using the angular directive `ng-bind-html` on the main page.
3. Inspect the rendered code after the execution of the `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`

HTML in the response:

```
<blockquote class=\"twitter-video\" data-status=\"hidden\"><p lang=\"ro\" dir=\"ltr\">The Good Dinosaur <a href=\"https://twitter.com/hashtag/Trailler?src=hash\">#Trailler</a> Movie: <a href=\"https://t.co/xQxGt5RAwK\">https://t.co/xQxGt5RAwK</a> melalui <a href=\"https://twitter.com/YouTube\">@YouTube</a></p>&mdash; Udin Media ™ (@MediaUdin) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/MediaUdin/status/672098352037785600\">December 2, 2015</a></blockquote>
```

According to the API,

> An Embedded Tweet comes in two parts: a `<blockquote>` containing Tweet
>   information and the JavaScript file on Twitter’s servers which
>   converts the `<blockquote>` into a fully-rendered Tweet.  If you see
>   Tweet text on your page but not a fully-rendered Tweet it’s possible
>   your CMS or editing interface stripped the `<script>` needed to render
>   the Tweet.
>
> Try switching to a “text,” “HTML,” or “code editing” mode to directly
>   input the pre-formatted Tweet information. Rich-text or WYSIWYG
>   editors can misinterpret pasted HTML code, which may interfere with
>   placing a Tweet on your page.

So what does it means "switching to a “text,” “HTML,” or “code editing” mode"? Where? How?

Excerpt of what I have in the HTML:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>

<div ng-bind-html="htmloembedresponse"</div>
```

Rendered page:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-video twitter-video-error" data-twitter-extracted-i144954813610521315"=true....
```

Because of this, none of the icons, images/videos, buttons are included in the widget rendering. A the documentation is very light at this point.

Answer (score 0):

They mean "Don't trust WYSIWYG editors to write HTML for you".

Write the HTML by hand.

Comment: Which translates into don't use the api? The api creates the html to render. And a JS widget equally from them, is supposed to render it. How could that be?

Comment: No, it translates into "Don't use a WYSIWYG editors to write the HTML that uses the API".

Comment: Look at the message again: "If you see Tweet text on your page but not a fully-rendered Tweet **it’s possible** your CMS or editing interface stripped the needed to render the Tweet.". Possible. Not certain. The problem could be caused by something else.

Comment: The point is that widgets of the type: <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"> with the video included are redered. The single video of the example in Twitter is also rendered as single video. I'm requesting the API for a single video widget and is not rendered.